# type error in func declaration

Tags: haskell

I do:

```
Prelude> "sone" ++ "otehr"
"soneotehr"
```

But such code:

```
addOneToElement :: [a] -> [a]
addOneToElement element = element ++ "next"

main = do
   let s = addOneToElement("some")
   putStrLn s
```

produces this output:

```
all_possible_combinations.hs:22:37:
    Couldn't match expected type `a' against inferred type `Char'
      `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for `addOneToElement'
            at all_possible_combinations.hs:21:20
      Expected type: [a]
      Inferred type: [Char]
    In the second argument of `(++)', namely `"next"'
    In the expression: element ++ "next"
```

Why I get this error and how I can fix it?

Comment: Also, you can (and should, it's pointless and confusing) drop the parens for function invocation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your type signature should be:

```
addOneToElement :: [Char] -> [Char]
```

(Or more simply, `addOneToElement :: String -> String`)

The "`a`" in your type signature is a wildcard - it can match anything. However you are trying to concatenate a list of `Char` to a list of anything - and there is no way to do that.

Comment: You meant list when you said array.

Comment: Cheers, fixed. I'm a C++ programmer by day, and my fingers were on auto-pilot.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using a type variable here anyway? The only type that *can* match is `Char`, since the second operand of `(++)` is fixed to `[Char]` (`"next"`).